# Proving the sum of the harmonic series up to $p-1$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Wolstenholmes theorem says that $1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{p-1} \equiv 0 \bmod p$. I dont quite get the proof, but I was wondering if the argument here is valid for the narrow case that it is divisible by p?

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{p-1} \equiv 1 + 2 + \dots + (p-1) \equiv \frac{p(p-1)}{2} \equiv 0 \bmod p$$

Regards (my first post on stackexchange :P)

Comment: It took me a few minutes to figure out that those are inverses mod $p$.  (It would be a pretty ridiculous theorem otherwise...)  Now it makes more sense.  That seems correct to me if $p\neq 2$

Comment: Yeah, it doesnt hold for $p = 2$ because then $\frac{p(p-1)}{2} = p-1 = 1 \bmod 2$. Thanks for approving.

Comment: According to wikipedia the theorem actually says that adding the fractions as rational numbers (not mod $p$) you obtain a rational number with numerator congruent to $0$ mod $p^2$.  So it looks like you are proving something different than the theorem.

Comment: At first I thought the theorem was meant to imply the partial harmonic series was an integer divisible by $p$ which is obviously false but now I realize you are actually supposed to sum the partial harmonic series and then look only at the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

According to wikipedia the Wolstenholme theorem states that for $p>3$ the following two congruences hold:

$1+{1 \over 2}+{1 \over 3}+...+{1 \over p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$

$1+{1 \over 2^2}+{1 \over 3^2}+...+{1 \over (p-1)^2} \equiv 0 \pmod p.$

It goes on to explain:

"Congruences with fractions make sense, provided that the denominators are coprime to the modulus.
For example, with $p=7$, the first of these says that the numerator of $49/20$ is a multiple of $49$, while the second says the numerator of $5369/3600$ is a multiple of $7$."

You have a correct proof that for $p\geq 3$ the partial harmonic series viewed as integers mod $p$ is congruent to $0$ mod $p$.  As you-sir-33433 points out this actually is equivalent to saying that the partial harmonic series viewed as fractions has numerator congruent to $0$ mod $p$, by multiplying by common denominator $(p-1)!$  So you have correctly proven a statement which is weaker than the first congruency in Wolstenholme's theorem (but still relevant).

Comment: I see, so you are saying that if we have a collection of fractions with denominators coprime to $p$ then the numerator of the sum is congruent to $0$ mod $p$ iff viewing the fractions as integers mod $p$ their sum is congruent to $0$ mod $p$?

Comment: Hmm, I take it back.  I was in a hurry and can't get my facts quite right.

Comment: I'm confused.  I'm trying to fix my answer...

Comment: Ah yes, Wilson's Theorem is the missing puece .

Comment: I think what you were saying was correct.

Comment: You know, I'm starting to think so as well.  I was writing from my phone and couldn't correct my comments in a hurry and started to second-guess myself.  The point, I think, is that $p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = (p\mathbb{Z})_{(p)}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1,2,...,(p-1)$ let $a_n = \frac{(p-1)!}{n}$.

Then making a common denominator:

$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{p-1} = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)} a_n}{(p-1)!}.$

Now what you are trying to prove is that $p$ divides the numerator (since it definitely doesn't divide the denominator).

But this is easy since by Wilson's theorem $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \bmod p$, so $a_n \equiv -n^{-1} \bmod p$.

Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)} a_n \equiv -\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)} n^{-1} = -\sum_{m=1}^{(p-1)} m = \frac{p(p-1)}{2} \equiv 0 \bmod p$.

And so we are done...without having to consider the philosophy of "reducing fractions mod $p$".